# Facebook Linter can't connect to site?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm getting a critical error when using the Facebook Linter to check og meta info.

**Critical Errors That Must Be Fixed**

*Error Scraping Page:   Can't Download*

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=theshinebox.com

The site/url work fine in a browser though...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked this, but it looks to me like your og:url value is incorrect.

Facebook will actually GO to that address to get the canonical version of the page. And you've written the address without the Top Level Domain, so of course Facebook can't download from it.

David

Comment: Get the same error when using the canonical version https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.theshinebox.com